# Angular Material Date Picker Default Date Selected

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

[This help me for date picker](http://demo.agektmr.com/datalist/),

Now in this `date-picker` i want today's date as selected by default.

can anyone help me how do set default date?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe an example or jsfiddle would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In andgular material i have used [this](http://demo.agektmr.com/datalist/) for datepicker and my issue of set current date is solved as follow,

Using AngularJs Controller,

#### HTML:

```
<input type="date" list="days" ng-model="transaction.date">
```

#### Javascript:

```
$scope.transaction.date = new Date();
```

(1) [google components](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html#)

(2) [datepicker demo](http://codepen.io/SimeonC/pen/XJdWPy)

(3) [material demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker)

Comment: @ESala https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker this one may be useful